# Open a terminal from ruby code?

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

Are there any system libraries that will allow me to open groups of terminals (as tabs not multiple windows) from ruby? I don't want to use the exec() method to open the terminal app... For instance I'm running about 5 different terminals in my environment (mongodb, redis, daemons, etc) and I want to write a script that will open up that group of windows and execute commands to startup up all of those processes. Any ideas? I'm thinking I might only be able to do it with Objective-C or MacRuby.

Comment: why Ruby? why not the native script language of your OS, and every OS has some kind of init.d folder you can add more stuff to it

Comment: @Itay Moav: "native language"? Wait, you think all software for Mac OS X is written in the same language?

Comment: I guess you can do this with a simple AppleScript. Not sure though.

Comment: @WTP "native script language of your OS" not "native language" for apple software. But, I see you understood what I meant in your next comment.

Comment: Ruby's `Open-URI` would be the perfect jumping-off place for this, because URIs define all sorts of services, both [officially](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and [unofficially](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Unofficial_but_common_URI_schemes). Unfortunately launching the appropriate URI handler is a problem because not every scheme has a designated app that has a console, and not every OS comes with a suitable app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [terminitor](https://github.com/achiu/terminitor) gem does **exactly** what you want and it uses rb-appscript behind scenes.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd say forget about Ruby for this, just script [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/):

http://onethingwell.org/post/455644179/tmux

Example from the post above:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d -s main
tmux new-window -t main:1 alpine
tmux rename-window -t main:1 mail
tmux new-window -t main:2 'newsbeuter -r'
tmux rename-window -t main:2 news
tmux select-window -t main:0
tmux attach -t main
```

Comment: This has benefit of working on any un*x (with tmux installed), even headless servers.  Plus, on Mac, iTerm 2's tmux integration can expose these as actual terminal tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to 
Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings Tab -> "+" (to create a new setting), 
name the setting "mongo", 
Click on the "Shell" menu item in the pane, 
Check the "Startup" checkbox and enter a shell command to start and/or monitor logs
Set other options to taste
Go to the Gear menu item (next to the +, -, Default), select "Export"
Save as a file "mongo.terminal" in your repo.

To open when you're already in a terminal, type
open mongo.terminal
(insert proper path as needed)

Now here's the kicker: you can go into the Window Groups tab and collect the special purpose terminal configs under one project name, export that window group to a .terminal file, and get them all launched together by opening it.

- OSX has a command called "open" which will open the primary application associated with a given file, as if the user clicked on its Desktop icon. This works on *.terminal files too. There are other ways, and it can get hijacked if someone alters the associations to "*.terminal" files, but that's unlikely and fairly easy to detect (your terminals won't launch).
- You can more easily select color/background/font etc. from the Terminal user interface this way, and get them into a repo for sharing and reuse.
- The exported *.terminal files are plist documents in XML. Most of the important data fields look like they are base64 encoded, so not very editable but there are a few things you can change if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
class Terminal
    def self.runInNewWindow(command)
        `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
        do script "#{command}"
        end tell'`
    end
end

class File
    def self.create(filename, text)
        fo = File.open(filename, "w+")
        File.chmod(0777, filename)
        fo.puts text
        fo.close
    end
end
```

### Usage

```
filename = "file"
#closeWindowCommand = "osascript -e 'tell app \"Terminal\" to close first window' & exit"
removeFileCommand = "rm #{filename}"
command = "#{RUBY_VERSION}"
path = File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)
File.create(filename, "echo #{command}; #{removeFileCommand}")
Terminal.runInNewWindow("cd #{path}; ./#{filename}")
```

### Full sample

> file "run.rb"

```
class Terminal
    def self.runInNewWindow(command)
        `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
        do script "#{command}"
        end tell'`
    end
end

class File
    def self.create(filename, text)
        fo = File.open(filename, "w+")
        File.chmod(0777, filename)
        fo.puts text
        fo.close
    end
end

filename = "file"
#closeWindowCommand = "osascript -e 'tell app \"Terminal\" to close first window' & exit"
removeFileCommand = "rm #{filename}"
command = "#{RUBY_VERSION}"
path = File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)
File.create(filename, "echo #{command}; #{removeFileCommand}")
Terminal.runInNewWindow("cd #{path}; ./#{filename}")
```

> file "run"

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
ruby run.rb
```

> **Execute the sample**

Open file run

### Results

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar setup using [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). You need to write a very simple .screenrc with the commands you want to run, and some specific screen commands to create and split windows.

Answer (score 0):

Elscripto is a gem that allows you to automate the opening of Terminal tabs running pre-specified scripts: https://github.com/Achillefs/elscripto